# How to optimize a query using a range with Mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, range

I try to optimize this query :

```
select id_store from receipt where receiptDate between '20151109' and '20151116'
```

I execute this query with the command `EXPLAIN`. It appears that no key is used. The index of receiptDate is not used. What's wrong ?

Here's the structure of the table `receipt` :

```
CREATE TABLE receipt (
id_store tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
id_receipt int(7) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
id_product smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
receiptDate char(8) NOT NULL default '',
qty float NOT NULL default '0',
turnover float NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY  (id_store,id_receipt,id_product,receiptDate),
KEY NDX_1 (receiptDate),
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

Here's the result of the command `EXPLAIN` :

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type   | possible_keys                                             | key                             | key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | receipt             |   ALL  |NDX_1                                                      |                                 |         |                                      |24789225|  Using where | 
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

The table `receipt` contains 24.789.225 lines, with a average of 15.000 lines per day (receiptDate). 
I execute the following query and I obtain 120.295 lines :

```
select count(*) from receipt where receiptDate between '20151109' and '20151116'
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should post table structure and explain result. We cannot see your screen

Comment: You can also post the data distribution `select COUNT(),receiptDate  from receipt group by receiptDate` and run the same query but with your where condition.Edit your question with both results,I suspect poor cardinality.

Comment: Your query returns all the rows in the table so there is no point in using an index.Indexes are useful when you need a small proportion of data.

Comment: convert receiptDate in INT

Comment: Mihai, thanks, but if you read my post, the query returns 120.295 lines. The table contains 24.789.225 lines.

Comment: Mattia Caputa, thanks. I cannot convert to INT because there is many many codelines sending a string as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indexed `receiptDate`, the database engine will use this index if the optimizer *thinks* it will improve performance. The optimizer takes its decisions based on statistics about your table. It creates these statistics in background, this is a mostly transparent process.

Now you are using a `MEMORY` engine. Because memory tables are supposed to be short lived, these special engines have very limited optimizer capabilities. You might want to force the query to use your index with the `FORCE INDEX` keyword.

Your date is stored as a `CHAR(8)`, this is slow because the engine has to parse all height `CHAR`. You will obtain improved performance with an `INT` (convert the date to `YYYYMMDD`). Your queries should still work since the engine converts strings inputs to int automatically.

If you were going to use the `InnoDB` engine, then you should put the date as a primary key if possible, because the primary key is also the `Clustered Index` with this engine, meaning the data will be physically sorted by date on the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an 8-byte (or 24-byte if utf8) CHAR(8) for `receiptDate`, use a 3-byte `DATE` datatype.

While you are at it, you could save another byte by making `id_receipt` `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` if it is only 7 digits.

Specify BTREE:

```
KEY `NDX_1` (`receiptDate`) USING BTREE
```

since `MEMORY` may be making it a `HASH` index.  `BTREE` can handle ranges; `HASH` has to do a table scan.

I agree that InnoDB is likely to be better overall.